# Your Apple ID or password was entered incorrectly - Eror while login

Tags: ios-appstore, login

I tried to login with my apple id to develper.apple.com and application loader

But is giving the error -Your Apple ID or password was entered incorrectly

I know my login credentials are right.

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the "forgot you password?" link and request a new password.

Comment: I tried using the 'forget password'' click and it sent me an email. however, after resetting my password it still have the incorrect apple id or password popping up.

Comment: Try to generate an Developer Certificated to your app id